# Convert inconsistently formatted JSON String to Object

Tags: json, jackson, gson

I'm having the below JSON coming in as a String input to my code. Since the string isn't uniformly formatted, overcoming the escape characters and grouping of the quotes to read the string and convert it into Java Object and sub-objects has run into issues

```
{"payload":{"details":"{\"source\":\"incor\",\"type\":\"build\",\"created\":\"1553855543108\",\"organization\":null,\"project\":null,\"application\":null,\"_content_id\":null,\"attributes\":null,\"requestHeaders\":{}}","content":"{\"project\":{\"name\":\"spinner\",\"lastBuild\":{\"building\":false,\"number\":0}},\"master\":\"IncorHealthCheck\"}","rawContent":null,"eventId":"bb357b79-069b-426d-8d21-8d04b06f5009"},"eventName":"city_spinner_events"}
```

I've tried using GSON, Jackson so far to try and read the String and convert into object and sub-objects. However, I've been able to objectify only the top level object. I face issues while I need to create sub-objects due to the escape characters and misreading of grouping of quotes by the parser. It throws errors and exceptions.

The expected JSON is as below which can be converted to object :

```
{"payload":{"details":{"source":"incor","type":"build","created":"1553855543108","organization":null,"project":null,"application":null,"_content_id":null,"attributes":null,"requestHeaders":{}},"content":{"project":{"name":"spinner","lastBuild":{"building":false,"number":0}},"master":"IncorHealthCheck"},"rawContent":null,"eventId":"bb357b79-069b-426d-8d21-8d04b06f5009"},"eventName":"city_spinner_events"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `unescapeJava`  from `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils`,

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```